# Fire jQuery after MVC Remote Returns

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, validation

Is there any way to fire some jQuery AFTER the result from an MVC Remote is returned?

I have a design like this:

```
<div class="wrapper"><div class="inner1">
<div class="inner2">Message</div></div></div>
```

and if there's an error, I need to change it to this:

```
<div class="wrapper error"><div class="inner1 error">
<div class="inner2 error">Message</div></div></div>
```

When the remote validation returns, it displays the message, but I'd like to fire some jQuery to add the classes to the divs where required.  Hope this makes sense...

Comment: can we get some more context, as in what you are doing on the server side, and the remote validation api you are using.

Comment: Tag with server side language and framework pls

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could just wrap the divs in a conditional and only show it all on error?

```
<%= if model.invalid? %>
  Add error divs here with MSG within
<% end %>
```

Or if your divs are more complex than shown, fill in a separate div class on error, either blank for no error or 'error' for the failure, and put this into the class of the elements using the templating language, e.g.

```
<div class="<%= errror_class %>">
```

Obviously adjust code for your templating language.

For a js only solution tag this with a language and framework to get the right people looking at it, as presumably you're looking for a way to set an after success callback?

Answer (score 0):

Going out on a limb a little here, as there isn't much info in the post.

I'm assuming that you are using the jQuery Validate plugin.

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

If you look at its options, you will see an event handler called `invalidHandler`. You should be able to hook into this event to update the class on your element.

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions

Answer (score -1):

```
jQuery('.inner1').addClass('error');
```

and

```
jQuery('.inner1').removeClass('error');
```

for the opposite effect

Comment: Doesn't really address the question.

Comment: @BNL his question was `but I'd like to fire some jQuery to add the classes to the divs where required.` and I provided the code, there is nothing more to say.

Comment: No, his question was `Is there any way to fire some jQuery AFTER the result from an MVC Remote is returned?`

Comment: @BNL he already has the response `When the remote validation returns, it displays the message`

Comment: But he doesn't know the event to use after the validation happens to run his jquery.

Comment: Where did you get that piece of information from, it's not stated in his question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16929/discussion-between-shtester-and-bnl)

Comment: It is in the first line of the question.